# "put to sleep" and "put to charge"

Tags: semantics

Does anybody know the rule in grammar that describes what the two verbs, "sleep" and "charge" have in common?

Can "put to charge" be a valid part of some sentence? like "I put my phone to charge". I feel like it should be valid but still feels sounds/weird.

Comment: Normally, in the US, I would say "I put my phone *on* charge" or "I'm charging my phone".

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes whether a word functions as a [verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verb) or a [noun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun) depends on the context. For example, in the following sentences, whatever comes after "put to" is a noun:

- He told the children the cat was put to sleep.
- The murderer was put to death by lethal injection.
- Their wealth puts to shame even the Rothschilds.

After the verb "to put" another verb can follow, e.g.:

- The killer was put to do this by others.
- The rodents were put to exercise on a wheel.
- The slaves were put to work in the fields.

In your example, the verb "to charge" is used in its [transitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_verb) sense. So, when someone says, "I put my phone to charge" – charge what? – the sentence makes no sense. On the other hand, "I put my robot to charge the phone" makes sense.

Examples with the [intransitive verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intransitive_verb) "to charge":

- The pimp put his hookers to charge more for anal sex.
- The coach put him to charge his opponent like that.
- The cruel dog trainer put the animal to charge at stray cats.

Comment: I'm not clear how you can speak with such confidence - "to sleep" and "to charge" sound like infinitives to me. Idiomatically (in Britain) one's phone is usually "put on charge" (though I have heard "put to charge"). "On charge" is a phrasal noun of condition, such as "on heat" or "on guard", I would have thought.

Comment: @WS2 There is one difference, though. 'To sleep' is intransitive but 'to charge' in this sense (as opposed to the military and financial senses) is transitive. If you say "I put my phone to charge" I would say that it was an elided version of "I put my phone to charge itself".  "I put my phone _on_ to charge" is different again, 'charge' here is a noun rather than a verb.

Comment: @BoldBen That's why I prefer "put on charge". It is not the phone which is doing the charging, and I have not yet found a phone which has the ability to "charge itself". It is the mains electricity which is doing the charging.

Comment: @WS2 Really I agree with you. I would almost, if not always, say '"put it on charge". I was trying to point out that, even if you accept "I put my phone to charge" you would still need 'itself' as the object since 'charge' in the electrical sense is a transitive verb. You could say "I charged my phone overnight so that it would be useable all day" but even then I would probably say "I charged my phone _up_ overnight".

Comment: @BoldBen "I charged my phone" is fine. At least, that's what I say.  Transitive verb, "I" the subject, and "my phone" the direct object.

Comment: @WS2 Absolutely, transitive verb with a direct object, perfect. Grammatically you could even use 'charge' in the financial or military sense with 'my phone' as the direct object, though I'm not quite sure what a military charge on a phone would be like:-) "Theirs not to wonder why, theirs but to do and die" and all that. Perhaps "Theirs not to make reply" might make sense when talking about a phone though?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with using "put your phone to charge" in conversational English. I would consider it to be a shortened form of "put your phone [away] to charge", and I don't find it strange (at least from the perspective of a ~30 year old American).